# Regex to convert IBAN to Local format

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I would like to convert the following iban in powershell with -replace

from

```
HU42 1177 3016 1111 1018 0000 0000
```

to

```
11773016-11111018-00000000
```

so how could i write a correct pattern to replace the 3rd space and 2nd after that? Then remove every remaining space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative

```
"{1}{2}-{3}{4}-{5}{6}" -f -split 'HU42 1177 3016 1111 1018 0000 0000'
```

Output

```
11773016-11111018-00000000
```

Comment: That's pretty clever.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Old = "HU42 1177 3016 1111 1018 0000 0000"
$SplitOld = $old.Split(" ")
$New = $SplitOld[1] + $SplitOld[2]+ "-" + $SplitOld[3] + $SplitOld[4] + "-" + $SplitOld[5] + $SplitOld[6]
```

or on one line:

```
$Old = "HU42 1177 3016 1111 1018 0000 0000"
$New = $old.Split(" ")[1] + $old.Split(" ")[2]+ "-" + $old.Split(" ")[3] + $old.Split(" ")[4] + "-" + $old.Split(" ")[5] + $old.Split(" ")[6]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a two-step [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) approach that is conceptually reasonably simple:

```sh
'HU42 1177 3016 1111 1018 0000 0000' -replace '^.+? | ' -replace '(\d{8})(?!$)', '$1-'
```

- `^.+? |`  removes the first space-separated token and the space that follows it, as well as all remaining spaces.
- `(\d{8})(?!$)` matches all 8-digit groups except the one at the end of the string (`$`, via a [negative look-ahead assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zerowidth_negative_lookahead_assertion), `(?!...)`), and replaces each with itself (`$1`, the first capture group) followed by `-`, thereby effectively inserting `-`.

Comment: negative look-ahead meen only match if next up instance would not match with negative-look ahead statement?

Comment: @NorbertPozsonyi, if I understand you correctly, yes. The subexpression preceding the negative look-ahead matches only if the negative look-ahead does _not_ match. Here it is used to exclude the _last_ 8 digits from being matched. See [Zero-Width Negative Lookahead assertions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zerowidth_negative_lookahead_assertion)

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to use regex to solve your problem?

```
$iban = 'HU42 1177 3016 1111 1018 0000 0000'
$splitted = -split $iban
(1,3,5 | ForEach-Object { -join $splitted[$_++, $_] }) -join '-'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyUzKTFPwVZB3SPUxEjB0NDcXMHYwNAMyDI0VDA0MLRQMAACMKHOpVJckJNZUpKaAtSgC2YrgPVzaRjqGOuYKtQouOUXuSYmZ@j6J2WlJpcoVCvoZuVn5inANUarxGtr6yioxMcq1GpCJdV11f//BwA)

The problem is more and more like Code Golf :)

```
$iban = 'HU42 1177 3016 1111 1018 0000 0000 1704 2345'
$l = 0
-join (
  -split $iban |
  ForEach-Object {
    if( $l -eq 0 ) {
      $r, $l = '', 8
    } else {
      $d = ''
      if( $r.length -eq $l ) {
        $l += 9
        $d = '-'
      }
      $r = "$r$d$_"
    }
  }
)
$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY2xDoIwFEX3fsWNaQJGa1pBwcFR4@bkbASq1DSAhcRB@XasBaVD03te73lV@ZSmzqXWXUdVcimwhXc4hUsIEUUIuFjblxAQXMTg9vSXiHiIZRCuPEK17XDC7qUq4BOA1ZVWDXrd24J9aXaXNGfH5C7TBi@LAHX1YatMPsAxHSBAzRzO6HlzxA62kLqW44/MTYfkNGahZXFrcmez7VGHb5xtsRmzq7Nfv/3vtXhCDc3oeUJ@k5ZMCTVd9wE)

Comment: Could you please give me some examples for the second code? !!$i++  what does it mean? and code which follows it. Sory for that...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `-split`, `-replace` and `-join` like this:

```
$iban = 'HU42 1177 3016 1111 1018 0000 0000'
(($iban -split '\s', 2)[-1] -replace '\s') -split '(\d{8})' -ne '' -join '-'
```

Result:

```
11773016-11111018-00000000
```

---

I see from your comment you also figured out a way of doing this, by:

- First place the "-" characters at the correct positions
- Then Remove first 5 characters ("HU42 ")
- Finally remove remaining space characters

```
("HU42 1177 3016 1111 1018 0000 0000" -replace "(^.{14})\s(.{9})\s(.{9})",'$1-$2-$3').Substring(5) -replace " ",""
```

Remember the `$1-$2-$3` need to be in single-quotes

Comment: Why not work this? 
First place the "-"
Than Remove first 4 chair
Than remove remaining space? 

("HU42 1177 3016 1111 1018 0000 0000" -replace "(^.{14})\s(.{9})\s(.{9})","$1 -$2-$3").remove(0,5) -replace " ",""

Comment: @NorbertPozsonyi Well... because as you can see, there are lots of alternative ways to do this. If you change your code to `("HU42 1177 3016 1111 1018 0000 0000" -replace "(^.{14})\s(.{9})\s(.{9})",'$1-$2-$3').Substring(5) -replace " ",""` it will work too.

Comment: Somehow i didn't know that it should '...' instead of "..."